# Perl CGI::Cookie not setting in Safari

Tags: perl, cookies, cgi

I'm very new to perl. I have made a simple login script that is supposed to set a cookie before redirecting to my form page.  I have tried everything I can think of but the cookie does not set in Safari. Several posts show slight variations and I've tried them all.

my code:

```
my $userQuery = "SELECT user_name , password FROM egi_users WHERE user_name = '$username' AND password = '$cryptword'";
my $result = $dbh->prepare($userQuery);
$result->execute()or die "MYSQL ERROR : $DBI::errstr\n";

my $rows = $result->rows;

if($rows == 1){

    #login is valid. Create cookie and send to patient_data page.                                                                                          
    #print("success\n");                                                                                                                                   

    my $c = CGI::Cookie->new(-name=>'login_access',
                             -value=>$username,
                             -expires=>'+1h');

    print $q->redirect(-uri=>'http://mytestserver.com/cgi/patient_data.pl' , -status => '301' , -cookie => $c);


}else{

    print $q->redirect(-uri=>'http://mytestserver.com/);
}
```

I've implemented all of what seems necessary fro CGI;

use CGI;
use CGI::Carp...
use CG::Session;
use CGI::Cookie;

The script correctly validates and redirects but no cookie is ever set.
I'm not sure what I'm doing. If you have a better suggestion in approach,
that would be great too.

Thanks for looking

Comment: Why are you printing your own headers instead of using the CGI module? And why use a JavaScript redirect instead of an HTTP redirect?

Comment: I've tried using the http redirects and they don't seem to work after a header has been printed, so if a redirect is necessary in the middle of a page, I find the JS method is the only option.  As far as printing header with CGI, I just saw that yesterday for the first time.

Comment: An HTTP redirect *is* a header.

Comment: okay that was cool. I created a redirect header and put the cookie and everything in it. It still doesn't set but it cleaned up my code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Status 301 is a permanent redirect. You're checking to see if a user is logged in or not, and then give them a permanent redirect if they give the correct username/password? How do they log out or log in as someone else? It will be impossible.

You need to clear your Safari cache and use Status 303, 'See Other', for this.

Also, your code is vulnerable to an SQL injection attack. Try:

```
my $userQuery = "SELECT user_name , password FROM egi_users WHERE user_name = ? AND password = ?";
my $result = $dbh->prepare($userQuery);
$result->execute($username, $cryptword)or die "MYSQL ERROR : $DBI::errstr\n";
```

Also, it would seem someone could log into your app just by making a cookie with their username in it. Who needs passwords...